# Obtener multiples objetos en PHP - JSON con Retrofit2

Tags: php, android, android-studio, json, retrofit

Estoy intentando hacer un proyecto sencillo de una galeria para android y tengo un problema a la hora de conseguir las imagenes del servidor y mostrarlas en mi aplicacion ya que solo devuelve la primera imagen registrada y lo que busco es que muestre todas las que esten registradas en la tabla, estoy casi seguro que es por que el json esta mal formado pero no se como es que debo arreglarlo...

Esta es la tabla de mi DB:

[image: Tabla]

Y esta es la parte del codigo donde "consigo" las imagenes del servidor

```
    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.createRetrofit().create(RetrofitInterface.class);

    Call<Imagen> call = retrofitInterface.getImagenes();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Imagen>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Imagen> call, Response<Imagen> response) {

            Imagen imagen = response.body();
            Imagenes.add(imagen);
            AdaptadorImagenes adaptadorImagenes = new AdaptadorImagenes(Imagenes);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorImagenes);

            adaptadorImagenes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Imagen> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Este es el php:

```
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $ruta = $aux['rutaImagen'];
                $descripcion = $aux['descImage'];
                $titulo = $aux['nomImagen'];

                $imagen = file_get_contents($ruta);
                $encodedImage = base64_encode($imagen);
                $respuesta  = json_encode(array('imgTitulo'=>$titulo,'imgDescripcion'=>$descripcion,'imgBase64'=>'$encodedImage'));
                echo $respuesta;
            }
        }
```

Y por ultimo esta es la respuesta del php (puse espacios en lugar de la imagen en base64):

```
{"imgTitulo":"Madoka","imgDescripcion":"Mi preciosa diosa rosada","imgBase64":""}{"imgTitulo":"Mami","imgDescripcion":"Mami Tomoe","imgBase64":""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está generando mal tu JSON. Lo que debes hacer en tu PHP es:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $respuesta = array();
    while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $ruta = $aux['rutaImagen'];
        $descripcion = $aux['descImage'];
        $titulo = $aux['nomImagen'];
        $imagen = file_get_contents($ruta);
        $encodedImage = base64_encode($imagen);
        $respuesta[] = array('imgTitulo'=>$titulo,'imgDescripcion'=>$descripcion,'imgBase64'=>'$encodedImage');
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
```

De esta manera no imprimes los elementos uno tras otro, sino que los vas metiendo en un array y al terminar de obtenerlos conviertes el array en JSON y lo imprimes.

Comment: Eso es todo, solo me falto cambiar el tipo de respuesta de Call<Imagen> a Call<List<Imagen>> y ya esta funcionando, que diosito te bendiga :'D